# React Typescript conditional param type with different set of values

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-typings, react-typescript

So i'm trying to get into the [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) and [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html),
When seems that i am getting into, i decided to apply it to a real case and then ...well you can guess... errors everywhere.

So i created [this sample case on Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-conditional-types-d5682?file=/src/Form.tsx) where i have:

- An `Input` component
- A `Checkbox` component
- An `useInput` hook

The useInput is the one in charge of managing the onChange, it started just for the Input element. Then i could have created a useCheckbox as well. But they would have been so similar that i thought, well good time to fight with the conditional types, since from javascript i can manage the type of value with a Switch for example

But now either `Input` and `Checkbox` are complaining because they could get some of the others value types,

[image]
[image]

hmm and this is happening in the useInput declaration. but Is there some way to tell the useInput hey the value would be just a boolean, or in the other hand could be a string,number etc.. ?

So the value can be for an input text o a checked value type ( a boolean )

```js
type valueType = string | number | string[] | null;
type checkedType = boolean;
type inputValueType = [
  valueType | checkedType,
  Dispatch<SetStateAction<valueType | checkedType>>
];
```

// useInput.tsx

```js
import React, { useState, ChangeEvent, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";

type valueType = string | number | string[] | null;
type checkedType = boolean;
type inputValueType = [
  valueType | checkedType,
  Dispatch<SetStateAction<valueType | checkedType>>
];

export type onChangeType = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;

const useInput = (initialValue = "") => {
  const [value, setValue]: inputValueType = useState(initialValue);

  const reset = () => setValue("");

  const onChange: onChangeType = ({ target }) => {
    switch (target.type) {
      case "checkbox":
      case "radio":
        setValue(target.checked);
        break;
      case "number":
      case "range":
        setValue(parseFloat(target.value));
        break;
      default:
        setValue(target.value);
    }
  };


  if (typeof initialValue === "boolean") {
    return [value, onChange, reset] as [boolean, onChangeType, () => void];
  } else {
    return [value, onChange, reset] as [
      string | number | string[] | null,
      onChangeType,
      () => void
    ];
  }
};

export default useInput;
```

i hope this sample is clear enough, since reading multiple articles with  `T extends U ? X : Y` are just too much abstract for a start.

Thanks in advance